# how to do text clustering from cosine similarity

Tags: k-means, pca, cosine-similarity, mds

I am using WEKA for performing text collection. Suppose i have n documents with text, i  calculated TFID  as feature vector for each document and than calculated  cosine similarity between each of each of the document.it generated nXn matrix. Now i wonder how to use this nxn matrix in k-mean algorithm . i know i can apply some dimension reduction  such as MDS or PCA. What I am confused here is that after applying dimension reduction how will i identify that document itself, for example if i have 3 documents d1,d2 d3 than cosine will give me distances between d11,d12,d13
d21,d22,d23
d31,d32,d33
now i am not sure what will be output after  PCA or MDS and how  i will identify the documents after kmean. Please suggest. I hope i have put my question clearly

Answer (score 0):

PCA is used on the raw data, not on distances, i.e. `PCA(X)`.

MDS uses a distance function, i.e. `MDS(X, cosine)`.

You appear to believe you need to run `PCA(cosine(X))`? That doesn't work.

You want to run `MDS(X, cosine)`.

Comment: thanks for reply.however my query is that once you get the result from MDS now how will you use this data for clustering. in simple words I am not clear how to use the nxn distance matrix calculated from cosine similarity function in to kmean or any other cluster algorithm.What confuses me to use this(square matrix of distances) is, that now dimension is changed from n to nxn. any suggestion please.

Comment: That's solved by MDS. After MDS you have a matrix of coordinates, not a distance matrix.

Comment: thanks.  but i guess MDS will not give me any cluster. I wish to group the data in cluster. MDS will be giving x,y  coordinate , how to use it in k mean than?

Comment: Yes, you can try using k-means on the output of MDS.